# Transparent PNG Images in WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp

This image is going around in WhatsApp, a PNG with alpha info. Only works as PNG if you reshare the original one. Everything you try to upload a PNG file (this one or any other) is converted to JPG and the effect is obviously gone.

So my question is how did the original poster uploaded the image? How did (s)he avoided the compression part of the WhatsApp *(because WhatsApp will compress any uploaded images which will result in losing transparency)* ? Is there any API or way to upload transparent PNG images that I am missing?

The uses of this could be very good for marketing purposes!

[image: pink and red lips]

Comment: Did you find out any solution ...? I am still struggling with this !

Comment: Nope, I didn't :-( I guess the first sender of this image was an insider.

Comment: Yeah I guess so, because I have tried every possible way, but as soon as it's uploaded, it becomes JPG (due to compression) and losses all its transparency !

Comment: I had the same idea, but couldn't get it working. I also tried index transparency using GIF and 8-bit PNG. All of them are converted, and their transparency is stripped.

Comment: Even a single frame index-transparent animated GIF gets converted )-:

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to share transparent PNG images via WhatsApp is to send them as a document instead of an image.

Thus, the image is sent in its actual size/quality/file extension.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You create a Whatsapp sticker. The easiest way is to download an app which creates the sticker for you from a png image. An example for android is "Stickers Maker for Whatsapp."

See official documentation if you want to know the technical side of it: https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/26000226. In case link becomes invalid. You can simply search for "whatsapp stickers."

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple trick!
As you may check before, Whatsapp change image file extension to .jpeg even it is png,tiff or gif. 
If you open Whatsapp downloaded image in a binary app such as Notepad you will find the real extension. For this particular instance the exact extension is Png with alpha channel in lips area.

The trick is using Whatsapp feed background as image background and the magic will emerge. 
Feed background is white when the feed is posting from else to you, then you see the lips at pink color. 
When you maximize the image, background is black, then you will see the lips sexy red. 
When you share the photo to another one, the background is light green, then you will see the lips with green flavor.
Bingo!!!

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to figure out that i was asking the right question, with the wrong lingo.

What you refer to as `Transparent PNG Images in WhatsApp` (pretty much my google query) is actually called `third party sticker packs for WhatsApp`.

Meta has a [tutorial for creating them](https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/how-to-create-stickers-for-whatsapp), optionally using [available sample apps](https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers). (as of Nov2021)

> Custom stickers must meet the following requirements:
>
> Each sticker has a transparent background.
>
> Stickers must be exactly 512x512 pixels.
>
> Each sticker must be less than 100 KB.
>
> You must also provide an icon that’ll be used to represent your sticker pack in the WhatsApp sticker picker or tray. This image should be 96x96 pixels and must be less than 50 KB.

Answer (score -1):

With the latest apk, you can share png images also in Whatsapp. Give a try.

Comment: Dude I am trying to, but its not working anymore !
I have a Transparent Image, But it doesn't changes the color !
Here is the photo : https://imgur.com/a/hbEcTjs
This image has two text's one on top saying "Text - 101" and one on bottom saying "Text - 202" one is of White color and one is of Black, but when I share it, it doesn't work, it just sticks to one color !